# How to autoload phar files(httpful.phar) in custom component in Joomla 4.3 (php psr4 or psr0 based autoloading)?

Tags: php, joomla, autoload, phar, psr-4

I am using a custom component in Joomla and using httpful.phar (https://github.com/nategood/httpful) for REST API. Instead of using the include or require statement, I want to autoload its namespaces and classes. httpful source has Bootstrap.php which does the autoloading. But how can I autoload all the classes and namespaces in similar fashion as other component's classes and namespaces are autoloaded? I am a little clueless here as this is a phar archive and I can't directly access its files.

I tried searching over internet and forums but did not get any similar results.

Comment: I’m confused. Are _you_ creating a phar or do you just want to use the phar from that library in you project? If the latter, I’m honestly not sure if that is even possible without wrapping it, but the solution would be to just use native autoloading with composer and ignore the phar.

Comment: I am not creating a phar file, rather using an already available one: https://github.com/nategood/httpful   (httpful.phar).  I didn't get what you meant by by ignoring the phar. Can I autoload all contents of the httpful.phar file using composer's autoloader? using dump-autoload?

Comment: If you read the installation, the recommended way to install it is using composer. PHAR files are not used with web applications (generally). Just require the library as you normally would with composer, and then require the autoload file